# Can't bind mount from /tmp on ubuntu ec2 instance to docker container

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, docker-volume

I've encountered an issue that I simply can't find any resources for online.
I'm trying to mount a directory under `/tmp` (e.g `/tmp/testdir`) on to a docker container without success, the respective directory inside the container turns out empty.

I've noticed that this issue only occurs when trying to bind mount from /tmp/, if I replicate the process from /home/, the directory in the container contains the expected files.

The host machine is an ubuntu ec2 instance:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

`drwxrwxrwt  19 root root  4096 Jun 23 08:19 tmp`

Here are the steps to replicate the issue:

```sh
mkdir /tmp/testdir
touch /tmp/testdir/testfile
docker run -v /tmp/testdir/:/tmp/testdir ubuntu ls /tmp/testdir
```

The output of the `docker run` command should be empty.

However if I copy `/testdir` outside of `/tmp` it works as intended:

```sh
cp -r /tmp/testdir/ ~
docker run -v /home/ubuntu/testdir/:/tmp/testdir ubuntu ls /tmp/testdir
```

The output of the `docker run` command is:
`testfile`

I would appreciate any insights regarding this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Double-check the path and user permission as I am not able to reproduce it using ubuntu ec2 `docker run -v /tmp/testdir/:/tmp/testdir ubuntu ls /tmp/testdir`
output `testfile`

Comment: Also here is the ubuntu release `Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
`

Comment: @Adiii Thanks for you reply, here are the permissions of `testdir` under `/tmp` and under `~`: 
```File: testdir/
  Size: 4096       Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 10301h/66305d Inode: 279218      Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)   Gid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)
 Birth: -```

```File: /tmp/testdir/
  Size: 4096       Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 10301h/66305d Inode: 269950      Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)   Gid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)
 Birth: -
```